# Can these two functions be turned into one by using templates?

Tags: templates, visual-c++, mfc

I have two structures:

- `S_BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO`
- `S_MEMORIAL_INFO`

And, at the moment I have two distinct methods, as follows:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::UpdateBethelServiceTalkInfo(COleDateTime datSpecialEvent, const S_BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO sBSSTI)
{
    const CString strDateKey = datSpecialEvent.Format(_T("%Y-%m-%d"));

    if (m_mapSpecialEvents.find(strDateKey) != m_mapSpecialEvents.end())
    {
        S_SPECIAL_EVENT sEvent = m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey];

        sEvent.sBSSTI = sBSSTI;

        m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey] = sEvent; // Update

        SaveEventsList();
    }
}


void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::UpdateMemorialInfo(COleDateTime datSpecialEvent, const S_MEMORIAL_INFO sMI)
{
    const CString strDateKey = datSpecialEvent.Format(_T("%Y-%m-%d"));

    if (m_mapSpecialEvents.find(strDateKey) != m_mapSpecialEvents.end())
    {
        S_SPECIAL_EVENT sEvent = m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey];

        sEvent.sMI = sMI;

        m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey] = sEvent; // Update

        SaveEventsList();
    }
}
```

As you can see, they are virtually identical. Is it possible to consolidate these two functions into one with templates?

Comment: You could make two overloaded helper functions just to do the `sEvent.sBSSTI = sBSSTI;` and `sEvent.sMI = sMI;` assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible by turning the function into a function template, and providing overloads for the assignment. The only requirement is that `S_BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO` and `S_MEMORIAL_INFO` are different types (as opposed to type aliases for the same type).

The overloads for the assignments can be implemented on `S_SPECIAL_EVENT`. The following implementation takes advantage of what is commonly known as [*hidden friends*](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1601r0.pdf). Something like the following should do:

```cpp
struct S_SPECIAL_EVENT {
    // ...
private:
    // Assignment overloads
    friend inline void assign(S_SPECIAL_EVENT& event,
                              S_BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO info) {
        event.sBSSTI = info;
    }
    friend inline void assign(S_SPECIAL_EVENT& event,
                              S_MEMORIAL_INFO info) {
        event.sMI = info;
    }
};
```

With that in place you can then move on to implement the function template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::UpdateEventInfo(COleDateTime datSpecialEvent,
                                                   T info)
{
    const CString strDateKey = datSpecialEvent.Format(_T("%Y-%m-%d"));

    if (m_mapSpecialEvents.find(strDateKey) != m_mapSpecialEvents.end())
    {
        S_SPECIAL_EVENT sEvent = m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey];
        assign(sEvent, info);
        m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey] = sEvent; // Update
        SaveEventsList();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since you're updating an existing value, you could just update it in-place, e.g.:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::UpdateEventInfo(COleDateTime datSpecialEvent,
                                                   T info)
{
    const CString strDateKey = datSpecialEvent.Format(_T("%Y-%m-%d"));

    if (m_mapSpecialEvents.find(strDateKey) != m_mapSpecialEvents.end())
    {
        assign(m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey], info);
        SaveEventsList();
    }
}
```

If `m_mapSpecialEvents` is a `std::map` and you have access to a C++20 compiler you could further tighten the code taking advantage of [`contains()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains):

```cpp
template<typename T>
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::UpdateEventInfo(COleDateTime datSpecialEvent,
                                                   T info)
{
    const CString strDateKey = datSpecialEvent.Format(_T("%Y-%m-%d"));

    if (m_mapSpecialEvents.contains(strDateKey))
    {
        assign(m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey], info);
        SaveEventsList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will look at this. The reason I retrieved the pointer and then updated it was because sometimes I find that maps don’t contain the updated data.

Comment: I have it working thanks. I am using C++20 so I have swapped to using `contains()`. But, my map is defined like this: `using SpecialEventDataMap = std::map<CString, S_SPECIAL_EVENT>;`. This is why I have to update the map I do. Unless, we can get the referenced object? I am assuming the `[...]` is returning a copy?

Comment: [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) returns a reference.

Comment: P.S.: If `operator[]` did return a value (as opposed to a reference) then `m_mapSpecialEvents[strDateKey] = sEvent;` would produce a temporary, assign to it, and immediately destroy the temporary again, without modifying the object held in the container.